# Using Shibboleth Attributes as Ruby Environment Variables (Phusion Passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, shibboleth

I am trying to implement authentication for a web portal I am developing Ruby on Rails (i.e. I would like to protect certain pages for admin access). It is protected by Shibboleth and I have a database for users (for the information I don't get from Shibboleth). The server is running Phusion passenger on apache2.4

I have two questions:

- The way I am planning to implement this is by using an if-else condition. I will be taking an attribute from Shibboleth matching it with my user database key to identify users. If it is an admin then I will display the content specific to admins. Is there a better implementation?

  - How do I set the environment variables on ruby as passed by Shibboleth? And how would I use them in the HTML page to implement the if-else above?

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "How do I set the environment variables on ruby as passed by Shibboleth?".

Comment: @rlandster from what I gather, you can set the attributes your system gets from shibboleth in attribute-map.xml. I want to use these attributes securely in my RoR application (preferably not as HttpHeader). How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of checking the authenticated username as delivered via SAML against a list of administrators will work.

You don't set the environment variables explicitly, rather, the Shibboleth software (typically `shibd` together with Apache's `mod_shib`) sets the environment variables. The `attribute-map.xml` file in the Shibboleth SP software maps an attribute delivered by a SAML response into an environment variable (or to an HTTP Request header).

Here is an example fragment:

```
# /etc/shibboleth/attribute-map.xml
<Attributes xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:attribute-map" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Attribute name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:eduPersonPrincipalName" id="eppn">
    <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="ScopedAttributeDecoder"/>
  </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

The above takes the attribute in the SAML response with name `urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:eduPersonPrincipalName` and maps it to the environment variable `eppn`. Unless specifically configured otherwise, Apache will pass this environment variable to your Rails application.

For more information, see the Shibboleth Consortium's documentation page [NativeSPConfiguration](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPConfiguration).

Comment: That was my understanding. Thanks @rlandster, that answers most of my question. I do wanna figure how/where I will check the SAML usernames? Ultimately I wanna limit access to elements on my view which can either be done in page or by having admin specific pages (essentially the same as user pages; with a couple extra buttons). How can I use the environment in my application to implement this if-else